Why not reuse a class name for an instance of the class in python?
I want to get singleton/module-like behavior without the hassle of imports. Are there any issues with just creating a class and then reusing its name to prevent other instances of the class?
For example, this class for conversions to and from degrees Celsius:
# create a class
class oC:
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return other*K + oC0
    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return (other - oC0)/K
    def __str__(self):
        return 'oC'
# reuse the class name for an instance of that class
oC = oC()

I don't want any more instances of this class, so it works like I want it to. However, I suspect most programmers would balk at this approach. Is there some unexpected behavior that makes this a bad idea?

Unless it's a singleton class, usually you need multiple instances.

This seems like a better question for [softwareengineering.se].

Why not use @staticmethod if you don't need instances?

Using the same name for different things makes it hard to reason about the code.  Remember that compilers aren't the only thing that needs to read it.

@Barmar added an edit clarifying that only one instance of the class is needed. Does staticmethod solve any issues associated with the approach outlined in the OP? If so, perhaps that is an answer...

@Mark Ransom if you still think readability is an issue, maybe that is an answer...

Sorry, your question was closed which means no additional answers are possible.  The comment will have to do.

This will shadow the class name, and you won´t be able to
access the class to create other instances of it.
On the other hand, if it is meant to be a singleton, that is, a class that will only ever need a single instance, then this can be a great approach in Python - way better than the "popular recipe" involving custom metaclasses, for example.

Thanks for the answer. Added edits to clarify that singleton behavior is acceptable/desired. Are there specific reasons that this approach is better than solutions involving metaclasses? Perhaps this way is simpler?
